"No document received" error message when trying to create an envelope
I am building a Next.js app which will also use the DocuSign solution.
I am at the point where the org user sees a preview of the template (which works!) and then, by clicking a button, should trigger the process of sending the document to the recipient (and receive a copy as well).
This is the relevant method:
export async function createAndSendEnvelope(
  templateId: string,
  projectOffer: any,
  orgUser: any,
  applicant: any,
): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const authInfo = await authenticate();
    const dsApi = new docusign.ApiClient();
    dsApi.setBasePath(authInfo.basePath);
    dsApi.addDefaultHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authInfo.accessToken);
    const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi(dsApi);

    console.log("Creating and sending envelope...");

    const envelope: docusign.EnvelopeDefinition = {
      templateId: templateId,
      status: "sent",
      emailSubject: `${projectOffer.title} - Contract for Signature`,
      templateRoles: [
        {
          email: applicant.email,
          name: `${applicant.firstName} ${applicant.lastName}`,
          roleName: "Applicant",
        },
        {
          email: orgUser.email,
          name: `${orgUser.firstName} ${orgUser.lastName}`,
          roleName: "Organization User",
        },
      ],
      customFields: {
        textCustomFields: [
          { name: "projectTitle", value: projectOffer.title },
          { name: "rate", value: projectOffer.rate.toString() },
        ],
      },
      recipients: {
        signers: [
          {
            email: applicant.email,
            name: `${applicant.firstName} ${applicant.lastName}`,
            recipientId: "1",
            roleName: "Applicant",
          },
        ],
        carbonCopies: [
          {
            email: orgUser.email,
            name: `${orgUser.firstName} ${orgUser.lastName}`,
            recipientId: "2",
            roleName: "Organization User",
          },
        ],
      },
    };

    const results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(authInfo.apiAccountId, {
      envelopeDefinition: envelope,
    });

    return results.envelopeId || "";
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error(
      "Error creating and sending envelope:",
      error.response?.data || error.message,
    );
    throw error;
  }
}

data: {
      errorCode: 'NO_DOCUMENT_RECEIVED',
      message: 'The document element did not contain the encoded document, or there is a problem with the encoding. No documents were found in the request.'
    }
  },
  status: 400

From what I can tell, after all my research (e.g., here), I pass everything that is needed to make it work.
What is the issue?
It seems like it is not using the template but expects a base64 encoded version of the document.

Thank you for using Docusign.
We appreciate the code sample.
One possible reason is that using this syntax creates a new empty variable:
{envelopeDefinition: envelope}

in
 const results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(authInfo.apiAccountId, {
      envelopeDefinition: envelope,
    });

Try using:
const results = await envelopesApi.createEnvelope(authInfo.apiAccountId, envelope);

To use the variable you modified before.
You may also check that the templateID you are providing is valid.
You can use API Logging to see the information that goes out from your code to the server using this guide:
DocuSign Logging Guide
As an extra, since you are using a template and provided the recipient information in TemplateRoles, you can remove the "Recipients" section of your code.
